# php-ffmpeg can't open stats file. Will run in Terminal if I remove temp file name

Tags: ffmpeg-php

I have a simple app that is trying to:
1) rotate videos that have a rotation value
2) re-encode HEVC videos so they play in Chrome (until Chrome supports HEVC)
3) stitch several of the results together.

I'm currently developing locally and in testing, I'm trying to scan the current directory for some example mp4's I have in there. It chokes on the very first one. Here is the code:

```php
<?PHP
    $files1 = scandir('./');
    foreach ($files1 as $file) {
        $fileinfo = new SplFileInfo($file);
        $extn = $fileinfo->getExtension();  
        if ($extn == 'mp4'){
        fixVideo($file);    
        }   
    }



    // FUNCTIONS

    function fixVideo($file) {
    $config = array(
    'ffmpeg.binaries' => '/usr/local/bin/ffmpeg',
    'ffprobe.binaries' => '/usr/local/bin/ffprobe',
    'timeout' => 3600, // The timeout for the underlying process
    'ffmpeg.threads' => 12, // The number of threads that FFMpeg should use
    );

    $resultFile = 'FIXED_'.$file;

    // create the ffmpeg object
    $ffmpeg = FFMpeg\FFMpeg::create($config, null);

    // open video file
    $video = $ffmpeg->open($file);

    // get the first video stream
    $videostream = $ffmpeg->getFFProbe()
                          ->streams($file)
                          ->videos()
                          ->first();

    //echo "<pre>";print_r($videostream);


    if (!$videostream instanceof FFMpeg\FFProbe\DataMapping\Stream) {
        throw new \Exception('No stream given'); 
        } else {
            echo "<video src='$file' width='100'></video><br>";
            echo "$file<br>";

        if ($videostream->has('tags')) { 
            //echo "has tags<BR>";

    // MUST WE ROTATE?  
            $tags = $videostream->get('tags');
            if (isset($tags['rotate'])) { 
                echo "has rotate" . $tags['rotate'] . "<BR>" ;

                if ($tags['rotate'] != 0) { 
                    echo "rotate not 0<BR>";

                    switch($tags['rotate']) {
                        case 270:
                            $angle = FFMpeg\Filters\Video\RotateFilter::ROTATE_270;
                            break;
                        case 180:
                            $angle = FFMpeg\Filters\Video\RotateFilter::ROTATE_180;
                            break;
                        case 90:
                            $angle = FFMpeg\Filters\Video\RotateFilter::ROTATE_90;
                            break;
                    }

                    $video->filters()
                      ->rotate($angle); echo "rotating<br>";

                } // if ($tags['rotate']    


    // MUST WE REENCODE TO H.264?
            if (isset($tags['encoder'])) {

            echo "encoding: " . $tags['encoder'];
                } 

                $format = new FFMpeg\Format\Video\X264();
                $format->setAudioCodec("aac");
                $video->save($format,$resultFile );
            } // if (isset($tags['rotate']
        } // if ($videostream->has('tags')
        echo "<BR><BR>";
    } // if $videostream instanceof

    }//function
?>
```

When I run that in the browser, I get:

> appL.mp4
>
> has rotate0
>
> encoding: HEVC
>
> Fatal error: Uncaught Alchemy\BinaryDriver\Exception\ExecutionFailureException: ffmpeg failed to execute command '/usr/local/bin/ffmpeg' '-y' '-i' 'appL.mp4' '-threads' '12' '-vcodec' 'libx264' '-acodec' 'libmp3lame' '-b:v' '1000k' '-refs' '6' '-coder' '1' '-sc_threshold' '40' '-flags' '+loop' '-me_range' '16' '-subq' '7' '-i_qfactor' '0.71' '-qcomp' '0.6' '-qdiff' '4' '-trellis' '1' '-b:a' '128k' '-pass' '1' '-passlogfile' '/var/tmp/ffmpeg-passes5ba267bb96d0abvdgk/pass-5ba267bb96e01' 'FIXED_appL.mp4' in /Users/[redacted]/test3/vendor/alchemy/binary-driver/src/Alchemy/BinaryDriver/ProcessRunner.php:100 Stack trace: #0 /Users/[redacted]/test3/vendor/alchemy/binary-driver/src/Alchemy/BinaryDriver/ProcessRunner.php(72): Alchemy\BinaryDriver\ProcessRunner->doExecutionFailure(''/usr/local/bin...') #1 /Users/[redacted]/test3/vendor/alchemy/binary-driver/src/Alchemy/BinaryDriver/AbstractBinary.php(209): Alchemy\Bi in /Users/[redacted]/test3/vendor/php-ffmpeg/php-ffmpeg/src/FFMpeg/Media/AbstractVideo.php on line 106

When I run it in the Terminal, I get:

> MacBook-Pro:videos [redacted]$ '/usr/local/bin/ffmpeg' '-y' '-i' 'appL.mp4' '-threads' '12' '-vcodec' 'libx264' '-acodec' 'libmp3lame' '-b:v' '1000k' '-refs' '6' '-coder' '1' '-sc_threshold' '40' '-flags' '+loop' '-me_range' '16' '-subq' '7' '-i_qfactor' '0.71' '-qcomp' '0.6' '-qdiff' '4' '-trellis' '1' '-b:a' '128k' '-pass' '1' '-passlogfile' '/var/tmp/ffmpeg-passes5ba267bb96d0abvdgk/pass-5ba267bb96e01' 'FIXED_appL.mp4'
>       ffmpeg version 4.0.2 Copyright (c) 2000-2018 the FFmpeg developers
>         built with Apple LLVM version 9.1.0 (clang-902.0.39.2)
>         configuration: --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/4.0.2 --enable-shared --enable-pthreads --enable-version3 --enable-hardcoded-tables --enable-avresample --cc=clang --host-cflags=-I/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/Current/Headers/ --host-ldflags= --enable-gpl --enable-chromaprint --enable-ffplay --enable-frei0r --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libfdk-aac --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenh264 --enable-libopus --enable-librsvg --enable-librtmp --enable-librubberband --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtesseract --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzimg --enable-libzmq --enable-opencl --enable-videotoolbox --enable-openssl --enable-libsrt --enable-lzma --enable-libopenjpeg --disable-decoder=jpeg2000 --extra-cflags=-I/usr/local/Cellar/openjpeg/2.3.0/include/openjpeg-2.3 --enable-nonfree
>         libavutil      56. 14.100 / 56. 14.100
>         libavcodec     58. 18.100 / 58. 18.100
>         libavformat    58. 12.100 / 58. 12.100
>         libavdevice    58.  3.100 / 58.  3.100
>         libavfilter     7. 16.100 /  7. 16.100
>         libavresample   4.  0.  0 /  4.  0.  0
>         libswscale      5.  1.100 /  5.  1.100
>         libswresample   3.  1.100 /  3.  1.100
>         libpostproc    55.  1.100 / 55.  1.100
>       Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'appL.mp4':
>         Metadata:
>           major_brand     : qt
>           minor_version   : 0
>           compatible_brands: qt
>           creation_time   : 2018-09-17T16:01:54.000000Z
>         Duration: 00:00:03.30, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 4574 kb/s
>           Stream #0:0(und): Video: hevc (Main) (hvc1 / 0x31637668), yuv420p(tv, bt709), 960x540, 4459 kb/s, 29.97 fps, 29.97 tbr, 600 tbn, 600 tbc (default)
>           Metadata:
>             rotate          : 0
>             creation_time   : 2018-09-17T16:01:54.000000Z
>             handler_name    : Core Media Data Handler
>             encoder         : HEVC
>           Side data:
>             displaymatrix: rotation of -0.00 degrees
>           Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, mono, fltp, 98 kb/s (default)
>           Metadata:
>             creation_time   : 2018-09-17T16:01:54.000000Z
>             handler_name    : Core Media Data Handler
>       Stream mapping:
>         Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (hevc (native) -> h264 (libx264))
>         Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (aac (native) -> mp3 (libmp3lame))
>       Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
>       [libx264 @ 0x7f89e0018600] using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 SSE4.2 AVX FMA3 BMI2 AVX2
>       [libx264 @ 0x7f89e0018600] **ratecontrol_init: can't open stats file
>       Error initializing output stream 0:0 -- Error while opening encoder for output stream #0:0 - maybe incorrect parameters such as bit_rate, rate, width or height**
>       [libmp3lame @ 0x7f89e0019e00] 4 frames left in the queue on closing
>       Conversion failed!

Answer (score 0):

Try this.. Change:

```
$format = new FFMpeg\Format\Video\X264();
```

To:

```
$format = new FFMpeg\Format\Video\X264('libmp3lame');
```